# How to import .dbf files (with more than 256 columns) to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2017, xbase

I would need once a month to import 12 .dbf files to SQL Server 2017. Files have dBase III version. They have a similar structure. They have no PK and no unique index and no combination of columns can be treated as unique index. Each file is around 1GB size and has 100K-300K records. Most troublesome thing is that all of them have more than 256 columns.

That said all MS ODBC/OLEDB drivers fail to read them properly.

The only thing I have found working so far is Devart (paid) ODBC driver.

Are there any other solutions?